# Inferring the existence of individuals using Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, reasoner, hermit

I am trying to infer the existence of individuals in Protege, and can use some help.

Consider the following ontology as the example scenario: Persons may be siblings. If they are siblings then they have at least one mutual/common parent.
I defined a class called "Person" with a subclass of "CommonParent". I define the "sibling" object property from one "Person" (Domain) to another "Person" (Ranges), and marked it as "Symmetric".
I created three individuals (Mike, Jerry, Suzie) and added two assertions about one being sibling to another. The reasoner (HermiT) correctly classified the individuals as persons and added missing sibling relations.

Now, what I want to do is to have the reasoner infer the existence of another (unnamed) entity being the "CommonParent" of each sibling pair (without me specifically asserting that there is such individual). Is this possible? How do I approach this?

[Protege screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtTAT.png)

Comment: this is not covered in Protege, would also be to weird to show anonymous individuals. Also, you have no parent relationship so far and for sharing something among individuals you usually need variables which in fact means you have to use an SWRL rule. But even then, the anonymous individual wouldn't be shown in Protege editor

Comment: Thank you @UninformedUser. 
It may be strange but it is totally relevant for my ontology, and I can see various uses for it in other ontologies as well. I will try to work out something with SWRL rules.
Still, if anyone knows of a solution (either using Protege or an extension) to address my original query that would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.